# having problems passing array to view

Tags: php, laravel

in my controller

```
$streets_mix= DB::table('m_Menu as m')->select('m_Menu_name as name','m_Menu_description as desc','m_Menu_price as price','R.rs_Rest_name as restau')->join('Restaurant as R',function($join){
                   $join->on('R.rs_Rest_id','=','m.rs_Rest_id')->where('R.s_Street_name', '=',$this->s_name);
                })->get();
 return View::make('pages.menu')->with('details',$streets_mix);
```

and in my view i have

```
 @foreach($details as $value)
     $value['name'];
     $value['desc'];
 @endforeach
```

my error message 
`FatalErrorException` in e35c8c51c47b58836bbdd69ba22fc85e line 28:
Cannot use object of type `stdClass` as array

and if i do

```
var_dump($streets_mix);
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#163 (4) { ["name"]=> string(3) "eru" ["desc"]=> string(81) "made with water leaf and oilwith litle salt.Can be eaten with garri n water fufu" ["price"]=> string(4) "1000" ["restau"]=> string(11) "Mouth power" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#164 (4) { ["name"]=> string(3) "eru" ["desc"]=> string(81) "made with water leaf and oilwith litle salt.Can be eaten with garri n water fufu" ["price"]=> string(4) "1000" ["restau"]=> string(11) "Mouth power"
```

Comment: it already says `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`, its an object, not an array, you've already seen the `var_dump` so you should have noticed this by now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view gets an array of objects.

Access the property like you would of an object.

```
@foreach($details as $value)
     $value->name;
     $value->desc;
@endforeach
```